# Detect changed files by content

Tags: files, editing

When working with files changed on disk, there are two warnings

- *... changed on disk; really edit the buffer?*
- *... has changed since visited or saved.  Save anyway?*

They're useful, but get very impractical when switching branches fort and back (as I commonly do with git).

Is it possible to make Emacs determine that the content hasn't actually changed (or has been restored to a state equals to what's in its Emacs buffer)?

---

The fix given in the nearly-duplicate solves the first part only. As @Stefan wrote, the second is easy using `(set-visited-file-modtime)`.

Comment: possible duplicate http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21137/fix-changed-on-disk-reread-from-disk-when-file-has-not-changed

Comment: FWIW, I think it'd be good to have such a behavior in Emacs, so I'd welcome a patch to Emacs which does that cleanly.  It might be easier to make it work well by patching Emacs than with a hack to `ask-user-about-supersession-threat`.

Comment: @Stefan A patch would be fine, but I'm not good enough in "emacsing" yet. Anyway, I'd suggest to rewrite the 50 line monster called `basic-save-buffer` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to tweak `ask-user-about-supersession-threat` to just call `set-visited-file-modtime` when the buffer and the file have the same contents, so that Emacs refreshes its notion of "which was the state of the file when I read it".

Checking "same contents" basically involves saving the buffer into an auxiliary file, and then comparing the two files (or loading the file into a new buffer and comparing the two buffers).

Answer (score 1):

@Stefan's answer solved it, I'm just adding the details. I'm using the following modification of `compare-buffer-with-file` from the [related question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/21137/13045):

```
(save-restriction
  (widen)
  (let ((original-buffer (current-buffer))
        (original-size (point-max)))
    (and
     (with-temp-buffer
       (insert-file-contents filename)
       (zerop (compare-buffer-substrings original-buffer 1 original-size
                                        (current-buffer) 1 (point-max))))
     (progn (set-visited-file-modtime) t)))))
```